# Вираз і вислів синоніми?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

В [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B20) вираз та вислів подаються, як синоніми.

> ВИ́СЛІВ *(сполучення слів, що виражає закінчену думку або становить
>   певну єдність)*, ВИ́РАЗ, ЗВОРО́Т, ФРА́ЗА, АФОРИ́ЗМ *(узагальнена
>   думка, висловлена стисло)*; ГНО́МА *(віршована).*

В СУМ-20 лише 3 знач. слова "[вираз](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10342&page=351)" ***те саме, що ви́слів***, а стаття ["вислів"](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=10739&page=361) взагалі немає посилання на слово "вираз".

Отже, чи можна вважати ці слова синонімами чи краще розмежовувати їх вживання?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Вислів* — **частковий випадок** *виразу*. Слово *вислів* застосовують лише до *виразів* природною людською мовою (української, французькою тощо); у той час як *вираз* можна застосовувати і у випадку природної людської мови, і у випадку мов інших типів (програмування, розмітки, специфікацій, математичних тощо). Наприклад, ми не можемо сказати *тригонометричний вислів* або *вислів порівняння*.

При цьому у випадку людських природних мов багато хто радить використовувати саме *вислів* (наприклад, [«Уроки державної мови» в газеті «Хрещатик»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53394/26080.html), [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2/)). Основною причиною на це, мабуть, є те, що в російській мові є лише слово *выражение* (що більш схоже на *вираз* і семантично, і етимологічно), тому вплив російської мови призводить до того, що про слово *вислів* дехто зовсім забуває (а дарма!). Утім, підтримуючи прагнення зберегти слово *вислів* і погоджуючись із тим, що воно звучить влучніше за *вираз* у випадку природних людських мов, я не можу погодитися з тим, що, мовляв, уживати *вираз* у випадку природних людських мов зовсім неправильно (по-моєму, *вираз* є просто словом з ширшим значенням — менш влучним, але прийнятним).

<sub>Також у слова *вираз* є два значення, що, на мій погляд, зовсім не стосуюються обговорюванного значення (мовний вираз/вислів) — вираз обличчя (тіла) і результат дії «виражати, виразити». Адже *виражати* можна не лише словами, а й обличчям/позою чи діями/поведінкою (і тут слово *вислів* теж незастосовне).</sub>